# is there any way that user can click on label that would popup menu bar

Tags: java, swing

[image]my snapshot  http://postimg.org/image/fi1bwpfoz/ :  how    can  make similar like menu bar as shown in snapshot. is there any solution for that.

Comment: and title label would be above from menu bar

Comment: What do you mean "in the middle"?

Comment: I'm starting to think this user is spamming. I've seen the exact same question being posted several times asking the exact same thing, linking to a page with a bunch of desirable girls waiting to be clicked on.

Comment: Post your images Here in this site. I have just upvoted you, now you have the rep to post pictures

Comment: And learn to ask better questions with some code and preferably an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)

Comment: i have posted image and is there any solution  so  that we can click on label and menu item are opened

Comment: please any one could answer that how could code to make similar snapshots. all tricks has been been applied asked questions number of times but no one giving a exact answer that i needed.

Comment: no one has given right solution . please help me  to find alternate solution of internal frame.i have placed my menu bar in internal frame. but i could build similar gui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `JMenuBar` is just a swing component, so you can change the layout as needed to center it. This post shows an example of how to do it http://java-demos.blogspot.com/2013/11/how-to-place-jmenu-at-center-of-jmenubar.html. You could do the same thing on an internal frame as well.

Comment: but any idea  how could i make similar like snasphot is ..pls help.

Comment: What exactly are you having a problem with?

Comment: i have to make my GUI similar as snapshot is. so could i d that is there any alter solution for menu  bar i swing so that on click of that menu item are opened and title ad label would at top of frame.

Comment: how could develop similar gui in swing i seems that menu bar is centered and title and label are placed after that.